# For IntelliJ, convert between abbreviated and labeled syntax for a dependency in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, syntax, dependency-management

Gradle offers two kinds of syntax to declare a dependency.

- Abbreviated:
  `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0-M1'`
- Labeled:
  `testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.0-M1'`

Is there some trick in IntelliJ to convert between these formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Gradle Dependencies Formatter*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7937-gradle-dependencies-formatter) plugin performs that conversion.

Tip: The code editor’s yellow light bulb icon menu with contextual menu will offer a "Convert to map notation" item after you install this plugin.

[image: animated gif demo]